# Search for archived emails by date, not keyword, in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, search

I'm looking to be able to get a list off all emails by a certain date, no matter where they are in Thunderbird. I feel like this should be pretty simple, but:

```
date:02/08/2013
```

AND

```
02/08/2013
```

only return emails whose contents have the date, or part of the date, in them.

I tried to use this add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/

but it doesn't have a global search, it only lets you search the mail in your current view.

No other addons I could find via Thunderbird's Addon search looked useful.

Comment: Oh, I'm silly. I was able to open up the Archives folder and it has all the emails sorted by date. I tried to delete/answer this question - but I'm too fresh to do any of those things I guess.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! When you answer your own question, community policy is to write up what you did and then post it as an answer so that other's can benefit from it as well.

Comment: Yes, but it won't let me for 8 hours...

Comment: It seems you need either 15 rep, or a 8 hours delay. I'll quickly whip something up.

Comment: then why don't you just make a new question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To filter email by date, you can click the on blue icon with the bars under the search box. You can then click on a bar, month or year to refine your search further.

[image]

If you want to include **all** your email in the search, type your email address in the top bar, and then pick the drop down option that includes your main email to see all email that you have ever received. You can then refine this as per above.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can only do this if you've entered a keyword to search for - I was looking to search in _everything_.

Comment: Sorry. The answer to my question ended up being much more simple than this. I just needed to open my "Archives" folder in the left panel, and it had all of my archived emails sorted by date.

Comment: That works, I had assumed that you wanted both a term and a date, but if you just want a date, the main window will work fine.

Comment: See bounty, looking for a pure date search solution (no terms).

Comment: @mattwilkie Found a way to do this, see above for details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of searching for your own address. This will likely work for many, but not if you have more than one email address (me@example.com, enquiries@example.ca, etc...).

Answer (score 22):

You can use the dedicated *Search dialog*, not only the *Quick Search Toolbar*:

`Menubar -> Edit -> Find -> Search Messages...` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

Then, select *Local Folders* or the appropriate account (see below how to search *all* folders/accounts), and fill in the *Date* criterion:

[image]

---

To extend this approach to really *all* folder, use the [SavedSearchThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/savedsearchthemall) add-on for convenience.

1. Install the add-on and check the following in its preferences:

   [image]
2. In the *Search Messages* dialog (first screenshot) press `Save as Search Folder` and save the search as e.g. *Date*. Now you have a new entry under your local folders.
3. Execute `Menubar -> Tools -> Update search folders target`.

   Now the *Date* search should be done on *all* local, as well as *all* remote folders. (Don't let you fool, that the search is under the *Local Folder* tree.)
4. Finished, all mails *on* or *before* (according to your setting when saving the search) a specific date are listed in the main window, if you click the *Date* search in the tree pane
5. Once you've created the *Date* search, you only need to change the date via the *Properties dialog* to do a new global search:

   [image]

Comment: Those 2 together are a good 80% solution, thanks! User experience would benefit greatly from having double click open the properties (and a date picker for selecting dates), but even without that this is better than a fake keyword search. ((Holding the bounty open for a few days to see if anything else comes up))

Comment: @mattwilkie I was surprised myself that no date picker was presented. However, what I was wondering in the first place: Isn't the beginning of your mail address (e.g. `matt@`) a good keyword for the global search? Because, according to the doc, "From address and To address" is searched. But of course, if you need to search multiple accounts...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date:02/08/2013` to search for a specific date after installing the addon [Expression Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmailui/).